# Why is setting a django FileField from existing file on the same partition slow?

Tags: django, file-upload

In my Django application I have to deal with huge files. Instead of uploading them via the web app, the users may place them into a folder (called `.dump`) on a Samba share and then can choose the file in the Django app to create a new model instance from it. The view looks roughly like this:

```
class AddDumpedMeasurement(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filename = request.GET.get('filename', None)

        dump_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.MEASUREMENT_DATA_DUMP_PATH)
        in_file = os.path.join(dump_dir, filename)

        if isfile(in_file):
            try:
                with open(in_file, 'rb') as f:
                    object = NCFile.objects.create(sample=sample, created_by=request.user, file=File(f))

                return JsonResponse(data={'redirect': object.get_absolute_url()})
            except:
                return JsonResponse(data={'error': 'Couldn\'t read file'}, status=400)
        else:
            return JsonResponse(data={'error': 'File not found'}, status=400)
```

As `MEDIA_ROOT` and `.dump` are on the same Samba share (which is mounted by the web server), why is moving the file to its new location so slow? I would have expected it to be almost instantaneous. Is it because I `open()` it and stream the bytes to the file object? If so, is there a better way to move the file to its correct destination and create the model instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a temporary file and replacing it with the original one allows one to use `os.rename` which is fast.

```
tmp_file = NamedTemporaryFile()
object = NCFile.objects.create(..., file=File(tmp_file))
tmp_file.close()

if isfile(object.file.path):
    os.remove(object.file.path)

new_relative_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(object.file.name), filename)

new_relative_path = object.file.storage.get_available_name(new_relative_path)

os.rename(in_file, os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, new_relative_path))
object.file.name = new_relative_path
object.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because I open() it and stream the bytes to the file object?

I would argue that it is so. A simple move operation on a file system object means just updating a record on the file systems internal database. That would indeed be instantaneous

opening a local file, reading it line by line is like a copy operation which could be slow depending on the file size. Additionally you are doing this at a very high level while an OS copy operation happens at a much lower level.

But that's not the real cause of the problem. You have said the files are on a samba share. Which I presume means that you have mounted a remote folder locally. Thus when you read the file in question you are actually fetching it over the network. That will be slower than a disk read. Then when you write the destination file, you are writing data over the network, again an operation that's slower than a disk write.

Comment: That is true. So as a workaround one has to explicitely move the file as in the solution I edited into my question.

Comment: Great! But as you know the standard practice is to post your own answer instead of editing the question. Please do that and accept it as the correct one. But dont' forget to give an upvote the helpful answer which sent you in the right direction :)